# While installing .apk file from my pc to android device using usb cable

Tags: android

I am sorry to ask this again as this has been asked many times and there are many tutorials to this question. But still I am not fully understood to do this.

What I have is a developed application's .apk file, Nexus 7 device and a USB cable. I am using windows xp. I do not want to use any File Manager, I do not have external storage as well. I have .apk file in my C:\Android folder.

I used:

```
C:\Users\bShah\Android SDK\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
shell@grouper:/ $adb install C:\Android\packageName.apk
```

Then I got error like **can't find 'C:AndroidpackageName.apk to install**. 
Please do not vote down my question. I think it makes sense to me. I could not solve myself that's why I came here.

Comment: @HERO It's the same problem. :(

Comment: After I posted my comment, I realized that I should explain why. That's why I posted as answer and deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try it with by:

```
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729\sdk\platform-tools\adb install yourAPKname.apk
```

You should give your path of your adt bundle at where it will be located in your PC.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually

> adb install C:\location\to\apk

You don't have to go into adb shell. When you go into adb shell, it's directed inside android. Not on your machine.

That's why when you type inside shell

> adb install C:\Android\packageName.apk

it return `Can't find error`.

Comment: How the system will recognize adb if it is out from the adb shell? I got error like: "adb"is not recognized as an internal or external command....

Answer (score 0):

How big is the APK file?  Can you not simply email it to an email account you can access from the device and save the attachment to the internal storage?  I've used this method a number of times.